# Counts of values dependent on two factors

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I try to find out whether there is a letter in column `V3` which occurs in each of two factor groups `V1` and `V2`. It will be clear what I mean with some data:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), b = c(4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), d = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")

df
   V1 V2 V3
1  1 4 c
2  1 5 c
3  1 5 c
4  1 6 b
5  1 6 c
6  2 5 b
7  2 6 a
8  2 6 d
9  2 6 b
10 2 6 c
11 3 4 d
12 3 4 a
13 3 5 a
14 3 5 d
15 3 5 c
```

Thus, for the first group `V1 == 1`, there are three levels of `V2 = c(4, 5, 6)` and in each level there is a `"c"` in `V3`. My expected output would be then something like this, setting all `"c"` to `TRUE` and the `"b"` in row 4 to FALSE, because it occurs not in all groups. For `V1 == 2` we observe in `V2` the two levels `c(5, 6)`, and now the letter `"b"` in all levels. Thus `"b"` is here `TRUE` and all others (`c("a", "d", "c")`) not (`FALSE`).

```
   a b d     e
1  1 4 c  TRUE
2  1 5 c  TRUE
3  1 5 c  TRUE
4  1 6 b FALSE
5  1 6 c  TRUE
6  2 5 b  TRUE
7  2 6 a FALSE
8  2 6 d FALSE
9  2 6 b  TRUE
10 2 6 c FALSE
11 3 4 d  TRUE
12 3 4 a  TRUE
13 3 5 a  TRUE
14 3 5 d  TRUE
15 3 5 c FALSE
```

Using `split()` and `table()` I am able to find the letters occuring in all factor levels of `V2` and `V1`.

```
a1 <- lapply(split(df, df$V1), function(x) names(which(apply(table(x$V3, x$V2) != 0, 1, all))))
a1
$`1`
[1] "c"

$`2`
[1] "b"

$`3`
[1] "a" "d"
```

Now I could split again the dataframe search for the letters and create the logical vector using something like this.

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y) x$V3 %in% y, split(df, df$V1), a1))
 11    12    13    14    15    21    22    23    24    25    31    32    33    34    35 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

But this is inconvenient and far away from an elegant solution. Therfore the question, which is IMO not a duplicate one.

Comment: The expected output is not that clear.  Why you have FALSE for row 4 and for row 6 it  is TRUE

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to reuse letters both as values and as column names in an example unless your intention is to confuse.

Comment: I think OP wants: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(a, d) %>% mutate(e = n() > 1)` - I'm not sure but, at least it gives the desired output.

Comment: @all have a look at my edits.